# How do I pause a Python script at the end of its execution so I can see its output if I am running the script through a batch file?

Tags: python, batch-file

### Intro

I am using a bat file to run my single python file. The python file is named "carpediem.py" and the bat file is "runcarpediem.bat". Below is "runcarpediem.bat".

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\17328\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" "C:\Users\17328\Desktop\carpediem\carpediem.py"
pause
```

### Problem

**The program runs fine and displays a Python Turtle screen at the end with my output, but I just want that screen to stay open and not close right after the program ends.**
My current solution was to slap a sleep(300) at the end of my Python script but this just causes the program to freeze and is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: you can add `input()` at the end of your program, it will just wait for you to type anything.

Comment: haha ty @Epsi95 that's clever, I'll give it a try.

Comment: infact, that might be the only solution. Programs will end themselves if there is no more instructions left.

Comment: @python_user I do not, the input solved the problem but I'm going to try this. Exit on click would be perfect. Do I put that line at the end of my python file?